# Issue in Showing Side bar in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have a strange issue in my magento site. Left Sidebar is not visible when opening a particular category page. But sidebar is visible on other category pages. I am not able to predict the issue. I checked in admin side, the "Display Mode" is "Product Only" for all categories in the store. What will be the issue or missing ? Can anyone assist ?

Comment: Not sure but looks like problem with missing closing tags in HTML markup..

Comment: @Mr_Green: Thank you for your suggestion. Tags are closed correctly. The issue was that particular category page layout was set as "1 column" layout. Now I set the layout like inherit parent category layout :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I was unknowingly set up **"Use Parent Category Settings"** to **"No"**  in **"Custom Design"** Tab and the page layout was set as **"1 column"** by default. Now changed **"Use Parent Category Settings"** option to **"Yes"** to inherit the parent category layout.